# wasn't (anything/something) for you

Tags: idiomatic-language

Let's say I invited a friend of mine to the yoga class I take. He shows up the first time, but not the second. When I see him again after that, I ask him...

*So you decided it wasn't for you, huh?*

Is this perfectly natural for the context? Or should I add "anything" or "something" between "wasn't" and "for"?

Comment: Your sentence is fine as is. *Something* wouldn't work. *Anything* could work, as in "there wasn't anything for you".

Comment: Andrew, I agree that the first sentence is fine, but are you sure about "something" vs. "anything"?  I would greatly prefer saying "something" to "anything" in this particular case because "something for you" seems like a unit.

Comment: @Vegawatcher I couldn't reconcile the negation (wasn't) with *something*